# authorize and charge a credit card for on demand subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal-subscriptions, authorize.net, ondemand

I am working on e-commerce application using asp.net MVC with C#.

I need to authorize the users who signs up with the application with the credit card.

1). When the user sign up, i need to get the credit card details and authorize the card by either Paypal or Authorize.net without saving the credit card details except subscription id or authorization code.

2). And whenever the user buys a product, i need to charge the card with the details given during registration.

Is there any sample code for Paypal and Authorize.net. please suggest

Comment: You've already selected an answer here, but http://sharpauthorize.com makes connecting with Authorize.Net in C# cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Paypal and Authorize.net sites have plenty of coding examples, including at least one C#/ASP.NET example. Visit [PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home) or [Authorize.net](http://developer.authorize.net) and go to either's developer center. (Both links in the prior sentence point to the indicated provider's developer center.)

Where I work, we've created many e-commerce websites for clients, and Authorize.net is our de facto standard for credit card processing. One solid advantage to using them is that you never have to store -- or even know -- a customer's credit card information firsthand. This is a very good thing as it helps protect you and your client from potential legal exposure due to data compromise. (Caveat: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.)

Comment: Thanks Bob. 
I got the answer for Paypal too. 
For reference, check out the link http://developer.paypal-portal.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=wppro&thread.id=12869